# Displaying Datepickers with Primeng

Tags: angular, primeng

Since upgrading my application to Angular 7, my Primeng datepickers have not been working. Datepickers do not display when I click on the appropriate field, and I am unable to enter the date via keyboard.

my.component.html

```
<label>Start Date:</label>
<p-calendar 
    [(ngModel)]="filterStartDate" 
    inputStyleClass="pCalendarInput" 
    [yearNavigator]="true"
    yearRange="2000:2030"
    [readonlyInput]="true"
    #startDate>
</p-calendar>
```

Is there a step I am missing here? Primeng 7.1.3 is installed alongside Angular 7.2.0. I do not wish to upgrade to Angular 8 at this time. I have imported the CalendarModule in app.module.ts.

Answer (score 0):

I was relying on deprecated style dependencies. To maintain the the correct style dependencies, include the following in your index.html:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/node_modules/primeicons/primeicons.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/nova-light/theme.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css" />
```

That fixed the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

You added `[readonlyInput]="true"` make it to `'false'`

```
<p-calendar 
    [(ngModel)]="filterStartDate" 
    inputStyleClass="pCalendarInput" 
    [yearNavigator]="true"
    yearRange="2000:2030"
    [readonlyInput]="false"  <===== false , for entering through keyboard
    #startDate>
</p-calendar>
```

For More info : https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/setup